# Correct way to dispose a base class?

Tags: c#, .net

I know this question has probably been answered before but I couldn't for the life of me find a question with this answer already gvien.

I have 2 classes that I call dispose on 1 of them, I was just wondering do I have to explicitly call dispose on class B inside of A's dispose? Or would it automatically do it due to it being a base class of A already?

The reason it concerns me so much is Resharper (A vs extension) constantly gives me a message directed to it.

> 'A.Dispose()' hides inherited member 'B.Dispose()', Use the new keyword if hiding was intended. The keyword 'new' is required on 'Dispose' because it hides method 'void App.B.Dispose()'

```
class A : B, IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {
    }
}

class B : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose() {
    }
}
```

Comment: If A inherits from B, why mark A as IDisposable?  A is _already_ disposable

Comment: So when you actually ran the code and called dispose, what actually happened?  Which methods ran?

Comment: @maccettura It changes the binding of the interface methods for objects of that type.

Comment: I guess you didn't get the OO concept very well... When you have a class `B` that implement `IDisposable` and create a class `A` that inherites from `B`, then `A` automatically "have" everything `B` provides (including the implementation of `IDisposable`). You don't need to reimplement the `Dispose` method on `A`

Comment: You should make Dispose virtual, and extend it in the child class.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza You're just assuming that nothing specific to `A` needs to be disposed.  That may well not be true.

Comment: @Servy you're right, in this specific scenario my words make sense, but on a real enviroinment it's better use a virtual implementation and overwrite it when needed. Despite this, I think it's clear that he is starting over this concepts and I don't think he will understand an architetural discussion for now

Comment: This page contains all the info you need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza If you make the method virtual and override it then the base class implementation isn't run.

Comment: @Servy we booth know that it's not an absolute true. It's possible to call `base.Dispose()`. I don't know what you want to prove so strongly, but there's no reason to keep discussing, you got your point. Congratulations  =)

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza You can call the base method without making it virtual too.  You call the base method by *calling the base method*, not by making it virtual.  Whether it's virtual has nothing to do with whether the base method is called.

Answer (score -1):

You could implement IDisposable as virtual in the base class, but this is a violation of the Liskov substitution principle. If you require derived classes to do their own disposal, you should do something like the following:

```
internal abstract class B : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeImpl();
    }

    protected abstract void DisposeImpl();
}

internal sealed class A : B
{
    protected override void DisposeImpl()
    {
        //TODO.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is B inheriting from A in your answer?

Comment: Because I read the question once and then wrote the answer. I missed that the OP was reversed.

Comment: You shouldn't answer questions that are obvious duplicates.

Comment: It isn't a clear duplicate - I think the linked issue is using the "official" dispose pattern, which is of very limited utility unless you're disposing unmanaged resources. Also, the accepted answer of the linked issue is a Liskov violation.